# Wrong alignment in highcharts datetime points with xaxis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Here's a fiddle with my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/v0bxdqa7/5/

As you can see, the point is not aligned with the xaxis value.

I've come to believe, from the examples shown in highcharts website, that the problem is with my data, but I can't find the exact problem with it.

Any ideas?

My options:

```
     rangeSelector: {
        inputEnabled: false,
        selected: 1,
        buttons: [{
            type: 'day',
            count: 7,
            text: '7'
        }, {
            type: 'day',
            count: 30,
            text: '30'
        }, {
            type: 'year',
            count: 1,
            text: '365'
        }, {
            type: 'ytd',
            text: 'year'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<small style="color: #666680">{point.key}</small><br>',
        pointFormat: '<span style="color: #acacbf">{series.name}: </span>' +
        '<span style="color: #666680"><b>{point.y}</b></span>'
    },
    xAxis: {
        lineColor: '#ebebeb',
        type: 'datetime',
        labels: {
            style: {
                color: '#acacbf'
            },
            align: "center",
            maxStaggerLines: 1,
            overflow: false
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        labels: {
            enabled: false,
            style: {
                color: '#acacbf'
            }
        },
        min: 0,
        floor: 0,
        minRange:1
    },
    navigator: {enabled: false},
    chart: {
        className: "line-chart",
        backgroundColor: "#f7f7f7",
        margin:[10,5,22,5]
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            marker: {
                enabled: true,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        radius: 5
                    },
                    select: {
                        enabled: true,
                        radius: 5,
                        fillColor: '#ffffff',
                        lineColor: '#ad49a5'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    scrollbar: {
        enabled: false
    },
    colors: ["#ad49a5"]
```

Comment: The time portion of all your datetime datapoints it `15:08`, when Highcharts ticks the xaxis, the tick is at the start of the day, not 3 hours, 8 minutes into the afternoon.

Comment: Here's a fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v0bxdqa7/6/

Answer (score 1):

Indeed your (timestamp) data is wrong.

Take the first one for example: `1370787037000` if you convert it you get `Sun, 09 Jun 2013 14:10:37 GMT` and that is exactly what's drawn on the chart.

If you want this point to be precisely on `Sun, 09 Jun 2013 00:00:00 GMT` its correct timestamp is `1370736000000`. You have to do this for each date.